# ASP.NET MVC Core foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a database first asp.net mvc core project and I'm not sure how to work with foreign keys.

```
[Table("tbUser")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("UserID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Column("RoleID")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleID")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

[Table("tbRole")]
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [Column("RoleID")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Column("Role")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

All the properties load from my database but the Role Role in User stays null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.Include(u => u.Role)` when loading from database. This works like SQL `JOIN`.

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Thanks! 
Also what is the difference between these and why does the 2nd one not work ?

`var list = context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Role)
                .ToList();
return list

var query = from u in context.Users
                        join r in context.Roles on u.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                        select u;
            var users = query.ToList<User>();
return users
`

Comment: In the second one you are just selecting users (```select u```) without changing ```Role``` property on ```User```. ```Include()``` does this automagically.